# Complex probability, or chance graphic

Tags: math, probability

I faced an interesting problem for which I would like to have a solution. I need to get a random number by the coefficient (`min + abs(max - min) * coef`), but not just a random number, the randomness of this number will correspond to the graph. Let's say that the random most often gives a coefficient less than 0.5, and less often more than 0.5. I have provided an illustration of the graph below. How can this be done? (Please give examples on JS, Python, C++, C# or Java)
[image]

Comment: Do you have a formula for the function that you have plotted?

Comment: You will find these interesting: [Wikipedia: Sampling from an arbitrary distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution#Sampling_from_an_arbitrary_distribution) ; [Wikipedia: Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)

Comment: Repeating Stef's question: "Do you have a formula for the function that you have plotted?"